# I want one calendar for datepicker textfield. In which I want that my calendar should show current date as my server current date. how to do it...?

Tags: javascript, jsp

Right now I'm using one `js` file containing some function of that calendar code but my calendar always showing current date as client date. I tried a lot but finally I knew that calendar of javascript always take the client date and time .So can you please tell me how my web application calendar will show me the current date as server current date instead old client current date

Comment: some similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5037861/how-to-display-server-side-dates-in-jquery-datepicker

Answer (score 0):

As you know that js always take client side date  so you have to make trick for it

one trick for which i go is

on the time of rendering html i will take server side date into an hidden field and when jquery calll the current date i will pass it as a current date

Answer (score 0):

You could send a value from the server which holds the current server time and create a new date object on the client side which holds that value, hence effectively showing the date on the server.

However, there has to be a VERY good reason for doing so, as this can be very confusing to the user.
Also, your server may be located in one timezone right now, and another tomorrow (if you move to another provider), so the dates may be inconsistent if you save a response from the user.
If you grow a bit bigger and need redundancy across data center, you will definitely have different time zones as you will want your data centers to be distributed geographically.

So, what's usually a best practice is to show the user his own time, and translate it to whatever you want on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this

`$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: "<?php date("m-d-y");  ?>" });`

Comment: Okay , Then please replace the server side code alone to get the current date . Hope that will work.

Answer (score 0):

you may simply read it a variable during page load like:

$startOfMonth= date("01-m-Y");

and assign it yo your datepicker field like

">